# Capture button missing from Azure Portal.

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, clone

I am new to Azure Portal but have good knowledge with VMware ESX and vcenter. I created some vm images in Azure portal (not classic) and need to clone them. However, all online docs point to "Capture" button which for some reason is missing from my profile. I found some docs about using AZcopy tool which is fairly complex. 
also, because I have some automation customized in the VM, running sysprep might break the tool/automation. so I prefer without running sysprep.
So the bottom line is that I need a way to clone single VM into multiple VMs without running sysprep. Yes I know about the conflicts and hopping I can do the modifications manually. But even if it is impossible without sysprep, fine. As long as I can clone them I'll live with sysprep somehow.

Comment: i dont understand what your question is

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using Powershell and sysprep. This blog post has a step by step of how it's done.

http://www.codeisahighway.com/how-to-capture-your-own-custom-virtual-machine-image-under-azure-resource-manager-api/

Answer (score 0):

If the Capture button is missing try to check whether your machine is a "Managed disk" one.

If it's not you can follow this tutorial to turn it on but I guess there's costs associate to it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/convert-unmanaged-to-managed-disks

ps: last time I checked "unmanaged disks" and I spent like three hours trying to understand why the capture button has gone.